# Pulling both the text and attribute of a given node using Xpath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I'm parsing XML results from an API call using PHP and xpath.

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $dom->loadXML($response->getBody());

 $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
 $xpath->registerNamespace("a", "http://www.example.com");

 $hrefs = $xpath->query('//a:Books/text()', $dom);

 for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
      $arrBookTitle[$i] = $hrefs->item($i)->data;
 }

 $hrefs = $xpath->query('//a:Books', $dom);

 for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
      $arrBookDewey[$i] = $hrefs->item($i)->getAttribute('DeweyDecimal');
 }
```

This works but is there a way I can access both the text and the attribute from one query?  And if so how do you get to those items once query is executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some looking around I came across this solution.  This way I can get the element text and access any attributes of the node.

```
$hrefs = $xpath->query('//a:Books', $dom);

for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
    $arrBookTitle[$i] = $hrefs->item($i)->nodeValue;
    $arrBookDewey[$i] = $hrefs->item($i)->getAttribute('DeweyDecimal');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One single XPath expression that will select both the text nodes of "a:Books" and their "DeweyDecimal" attribute, is the following

`//a:Books/text() | //a:Books/@DeweyDecimal`

**Do note** the use of the XPath's union operator in the expression above.

**Another note**: try to avoid using the "//" abbreviation as it may cause the whole XML document to be traversed and thus is very expensive. It is recommended to use a more specific XPath expression (such as consisting of a chain of specific location steps) always when the structure of the XML document is known.

Answer (score 2):

If your're just retrieving values from your XML document, [SimpleXML](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) might be the leaner, faster and memory-friendlier solution:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($response->getBody());
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('a', 'http://www.example.com');
$books=$xml->xpath('//a:Books');
foreach ($books as $i => $book) {
    $arrBookTitle[$i]=(string)$book;
    $arrBookDewey[$i]=$book['DeweyDecimal'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you query for the concatenation?

```
$xpath->query('concat(//a:Books/text(), //a:Books/@DeweyDecimal)', $dom);
```

XSLT is an expression language in itself, and you can construct whatever specific format of return value you want from within the expression.

Comment: Then would I just use the item->data and item->getAttribute to pull the results?

Comment: I'm not sure how PHP's XSLT library works, but you might be able to get it with just item->data. It's worth a try, anyway.